# How to make the FIRST separator of Table View transparent (opaque)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

1. How to identify the *exactly* first separator? Or by Xcode. (how better to make a reference)
2. How to write it? 
   MyTableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor NO COLOUR]

[image]
[image]

Trying to solve this programmatically!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

separatorColor is the property of UITableView. Whatever value you assign to it last, it will override that value. So you won't be able to set different colors for different cells.

You can create your own UIView on each cell as separator with height = 1px and width as that of tableViewCell. 
Hide the separator view for first cell or make the background color clear. 
Assign any color you want for rest of the cells.

Comment: Thx ... i knew it , just hoped to find new solution( 
However, i guess you can change the priority ... but how ...?)

Answer (score 0):

You can take help of **`willDisplayCell`**

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear
    } else {
        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.green
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this out before posting?)